# Google Chrome - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I don't know if this question should be asked on this site, but I was sent here from Server Fault.

I have been searching for a while, and nothing has seemed to work.

The problem is that when I try to connect to http://en.skill.gameforge.com/ I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. It does not happen on any other sites.

Here's what I've already tried:

- Disabling my firewall
- Changing my networks mtu to 1472
- Connect to wireless instead of ethernet

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Does it work in other browsers or in Chrome incognito mode ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like It does not work in any browsers, and not on other devices either

Comment: How are you connected to internet ? It opens fine for us here so this could be your router at home. Try a proxy maybe

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Works fine, do you have an idea on  how to fix it?

Comment: How are you connected to internet ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Ethernet

Comment: Router provided by ISP ? What kind of router ? Office network ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40726/discussion-between-itzbentethepig-and-the-it-guy-you-dont-like).

Comment: Have same issue. tl;dr. Can't open website https://angular.io/. Connection - Ethernet. Router provided by ISP. Router is Cisco EPC3825. Tried all of the above as well. I'm able to access from laptop in same network, but through Wireless connetion. Haven't tried Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this site was accessible over proxy.

During chat with OP, found no block/filter so had him unplug his router (*Netgear WGR614v9*) and site was accessible after a while.

Must be a case of outdated firmware on router or maybe just be asking for a reset.